# Loading UIImage into memory to avoid hanging when assigning to view

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have a scroll view setup with paging to show several blueprints that are a few mb each. I am trying to load the closest blueprints manually into memory while the user is about to interact with the scrollview. That way when I assign the image to the view to be rendered, the processing time is much quicker than loading from disk.

The problem is the images are loading into memory but aren't taking the same amount of memory as they should when applied. I assume this is because the render size is different? And I am still getting a hang when I assign the UIImageView.image to use my precached image as if it isn't using the memory. What am I doing wrong? I need to avoid any delays when assigning the image.

Here i am trying to cache the images by drawing them into memory and then storing the UIImage in an array to pull from later

```
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path + String(index) + ".png")
            let imageData: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
            self.loadedBuffer.append(image!)
```

Here is how I later assign the images to the 3 views, which causes a noticeable hiccup. This is the three views being assigned the 3 precached images.

```
    for index in 0...loadedBuffer.count - 1
    {
        self.planImages[index].image = loadedBuffer[index]
    }
```

EDITED: Tried to write a clearer description of what is happening and what I WANT to happen. Thanks for looking!

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of these images, and what size are you displaying them?

Comment: Calling `Data(contentsOf: url)` is synchronous and will stall.. plus you are loading data twice.. First you are loading the image into `Data`.. then you are loading `data` into `UIImage`.. double the work.. It's slower than just calling `UIImage(contentsOfFile: path + String(index) + ".png")`

Comment: I don't think it is loading the data twice. If I just assign UIImage using contentsOf: url nothing in my memory foot print changes, unless I am actually showing the image in a view. I am trying to load this into memory for use later, so I try to force the load by using the Data method.

Comment: The problem is that `UIImage` keeps the uncompressed image data. It only gets decompressed once it needs to be displayed. This explains both the lag and why the memory size is smaller than expected. See this article on how to do the decompression in the background: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/

Comment: Thanks so much for that article Sven! That was what I was looking for in terms of understanding and logic. I just need to convert this over to swift and figure out how to decompress the image and store it for use. Thanks again!